# PHP count function

Tags: php

I have to count the numbers which is divisible by 5.

Here is my code,

```
$num = array(4, 25, 60, 7, 8);

foreach ($num as $numbers) {
    if (($numbers % 5) == 0) {
        echo count($numbers); 
    }
}
```

Output of above program is 11. But output should be 2. Please give me solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `count(some number)` is 1, and you have two matches. So.... you get two 1s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something more like the following perhaps.

```
$num = array(4, 25, 60, 7, 8);
$numbers=array();

foreach( $num as $number ) {
    if( $number % 5  == 0 ) $numbers[]=$number;
}
echo count( $numbers );
```

or alternatively using `array_walk` and a custom callback function

```
function mod5($item,$key,$arr){
    if($item %5==0)$arr[]=$item;
}
array_walk( $num,'mod5',&$numbers);
echo count($numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way also,

```
function divisibleby5($var){
 return $var % 5 == 0;
}

$num = array(4, 25, 60, 7, 8);
echo count(array_filter($num,'divisibleby5');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$nums = array(4, 25, 60, 7, 8);
```

To only count:

-Basic:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($nums as $num) {
    if ( $num % 5 == 0 ) $count++;
}
```

-Playing with types:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($nums as $num) {
    $count += !($num % 5);
}
```

<sup>*`$num % 5` returns an integer, `!($num % 5)` returns a boolean but since it is used as operand with the `+` operator, `false` and `true` act like `0` and `1`.*</sup>

-Functional version using `array_reduce`:

```
$count = array_reduce($nums, function($c, $i) { return $c + !($i % 5); });
```

To filter items, use the well named `array_filter`:

```
$result = array_filter($nums, function ($i) { return $i % 5 == 0; });
```

and count the number of items after if you want:

```
$count = count($result);
```

Comment: I like that `playing with types` piece, neat!

Answer (score 0):

Here Output is 1 and 1. Not 11 (eleven)
You can try it

```
 echo count($numbers)."<br>";
```

your solution: 
Output will be 2 if you increment count variable value after enter the if condition

```
<?php
$num = array(4, 25, 60, 7, 8);
$count = 0;

foreach($num as $numbers) {

  if (($numbers % 5) == 0) {
    $count++;
  }
}
echo $count;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the event you want to print the numbers also

```
$a=array(); //initialized empty array
    $num = array(4, 25, 60, 7, 8); 
    foreach($num as $numbers){ 
        if(($numbers % 5) == 0){ 
            $a=$numbers; //store values into the array
        } 
    }
    echo count($a); // echo the count of the array
echo implode('<br>',$a);
```

**OR if you just need the count**

```
$a=0; //initalize $a
$num = array(4, 25, 60, 7, 8); 
foreach($num as $numbers){ 
    if(($numbers % 5) == 0){ 
        $a++; //increment a
    } 
}
```

echo $a

Comment: Please clarify what you have changed and why. This would make this answer a better one (:

Comment: So I initaized $a=array();     then inside your foreach loop I stored the numbers that matched your if statement into $a at index 0.Now since all the matched numbers are in my $a variable   outside the for each I count all the values and echo the count .......on a side note if you want you could also store the data into $a instead of $a[] as $a will create more sub arrays   if you wanna check try both out. And where you echo the count just use var_dump($a);  to see what the arrays look like $a will create a single dimension and $a[] will create a 2 dimension

Comment: I initialized $a as an empty array. So that when used inside the for each loop it will store all the values instead of replacing the values

Comment: Ohh and BTW the code  provide is doing just that its not echoing 11 it echoing 11 one one that's what I meant by replacing.

Comment: For clarification, I'm just a random dude on stackoverflow and not the one who ask this question (:

Comment: yea i saw   was on my phone earlier :P